# How to find out how many times there was borrowing in a subtraction equation with large base 2000 numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say that I have two large numbers(about 5000 digits) that are both in base 2000. **If I were to subtract those numbers, is there a way to find out how many times someone borrowed from the next digit over in the base 2000 system using basic algebra?** All ideas and equations would be very helpful. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Other than comparing digits of the same place value, for each of the 5000 digits?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the numbers are $a=(d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_1d_0)_{2000}$ and $b=(e_ne_{n-1}\ldots e_1e_0)_{2000}$, where $a\ge b$, and we’re considering $a-b$. (The representation of $b$ may have leading zeroes.)

1. Set a counter $c$ and an index $k$ to $0$.
2. If $e_k>d_k$, increase $c$ and $e_{k+1}$ by $1$. (The assumption that $a\ge b$ ensures that when $k=m$, $e_k\le d_k$, so that we’ll not need to consider $e_{m+1}$.)
3. Increase $k$ by $1$.
4. If $k\le m$, go to step 2; otherwise stop.

The value of $c$ is the number of borrowings. (A borrowing from several places to the right is counted once for each place, not as a single borrowing.)